# How to get data from remote server database to ios app

Tags: ios

Iam new to ios development and in my app i want to fetch data from remote server database to my application.please tell me how to do this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For that purpose, you can use webservice either JSON or XML.
You can study about JSON parsing from the below link

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: Thank u very much this helped me alot :):) can u please gimme information about what is asihttprequest heard that asihttprequest also used for fetching data from remote server db.

Comment: asihttprequest is not an another method. asihttprequest are used to invoke Http Requests.it is a framework that makes communication with the webserver easier.  http://www.mobile.safilsunny.com/asihttprequest-ios-tutorials/  if you have any doubts,pls feel free to ask it and please accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

The usual practice is to expose some RESTful webservices which extend the data from database to a mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a REST API. Which is the best and fast.
JSON is normally better than XML because is more compact.

you can also use this very light weightlib: [JNRestClient](https://github.com/jonasman/JNRestClient)